# jQuery Slider script not stopping

Tags: jquery

I am building a mobile version of a site and have a slider on the home page, works fine, but when I go to any other page the slider seems to be running still and automatically returns the browser to the home page. How do I stop this from happening, how do I stop the slider script running on exiting the home page? I've done a fair bit a searching but I've not found anything that answers this for me.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated, I'm pretty much at the limit of my jQuery knowledge.

http://waitakeries.businesscatalyst.com/mobile/index.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#slides').superslides({
        hashchange: true,
        play: 7000
    });


    //slide pauses whilsts cursor in screen window
    $('#slides').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).superslides('stop');
    console.log('Stopped')
  });

    //slide starts on cursor leaving screen window
    $('#slides').on('mouseleave', function() {
      $(this).superslides('start');
      console.log('Started')
    });

});
```

Comment: 1. Mobile devices do not have `mouse` so you should re consider using mouse events there. My guess, since there is no mouse, the mouse events are not triggered, so the two events are never called. 2. Also you used `mouseleave` to restart, think of the time when the mouse is over menu?.. it will still trigger the `mouseleave` event, even if its not really supposed to

Comment: Thanks for your attention to this! You're right, I got rid of the mouse events. The site is no longer returning to the home page on clicking through to the About page, but it appears that the slider script is still running as the url is still updating with index.html#1, index.html#2, index.html#3 and index.html#4

Comment: Because you are initialising the slider on eery page, so the slider will run .. `$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#slides').superslides({`

Comment: Ok, now I am confused. That only appears on the index page, it isn't on the about.html page as well. Are you saying because I've initialised it on index page it is still running on all other pages?

Comment: Yes, it's not that you loaded it, it probably is the theme. When I hit this with browser - http://waitakeries.businesscatalyst.com/mobile/about.html the content is not sliding, but when I go there click the menu, the slider is running and if you check the page source, you can see that it is still inside the index.html but only content got changed, so it is probably the theme you are using, which for mobile versions, instead of navigating, loading the contents from the page.

Comment: May be a workaround would be to stop the slide when a menu item is clicked

Comment: Hmm, think I need to go back to the starting point, I think the collapsing menu is causing a problem, even the logo link in the banner is not working as a return to index.html link. I'll see what i can do. Thanks for your thoughts Mahmud.